# Apply change record of property to another similar property

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to *apply* the changes provided by an observer to another object (similar object as the one observed) ?

---

E.g:

```
  properties: {

    boardBucket: {
      type: Object,
      value: {
        items: [],
        currentBoardId: 1
      }
    },
    remoteBoardBucket: { // let's assume this is on another client
      type: Object,
      value: {
        items: [],
        currentBoardId: 1
      }
    }
  },

  observers: [
    "_boardBucketChanged(boardBucket.*)"
  ],

  _boardBucketChanged: function(changeRecord) {
    // `applyChanges()` doesn't exist but can it be done?
    this.remoteBoardBucket.applyChanges(changeRecord);
  }
```

#### Why I'm asking this:

I'm building a collaborative editor where both parties manipulate their *own* `boardBucket`, adding/removing `items`(boards) to it and `adding/removing` items in those boards (`boardBucket.items[2].boardItems` is an array for each board that holds items in that board).

- The clients communicate via web-sockets between them and I'd like to see if it's possible to send *only* the `changeRecord` through the sockets and have it applied on the other-client's `boardBucket`.
- This will speed up things significantly as it negates the need to send the whole `boardBucket` back and forth (I'm not really doing this but for the sake of the question I'm putting it out here)
- An important note here is that I'm observing *nested arrays* as well. While `board.items` is an array which holds the boards, each board also holds another array called `boardItems` which holds the items in those boards. Therefore there is an arbitrary number of levels of depth of changes I'm observing here.